# LitRPG where MC has skeletal appearance due to penalty

Tags: story-identification, litrpg

I'm looking for a specific LitRPG where the main character loses 2 points of Charisma or something, and his appearance is penalized. Instead of being handsome, he has a skeletal appearance. (Not good for gaining new allies).
I believe that part of the rules was that for humans, the difference between the minimum and maximum stat couldn't be more than ten. When he lost the Charisma, the difference became more than ten which is why the penalty was so severe.

One of his allies/friends was of another race. (Minotaur? another "tough" race?) And the rules for that race allowed for a a greater difference in stats.

Edit: It's NOT the completionist chronicles: I've never read anything by Krout.

It's not Ascend Online either. I opened my copy and skimmed it a little. The stats don't match up.

Once the MC lost his charisma, his maximum stat was somewhere between 24-27. Don't remember exactly. He avoided leveling his maximum stat so the difference wouldn't increase. And penalty become worse.

I think the description was that his skin was stretched very tightly over his skull, giving him a skeletal appearance. So people who already knew him continued to trust him. But he was aware it would be harder to gain new allies.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Seaborn, on Royal Road. [Seaborn](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/30131/seaborn)

> What was I lagging in now? A rule of thumb was you didn’t have to worry about repercussions unless there was a disparity of 10 or more points between attributes. What those attributes were then dictated the result. Blake, for instance, had highly developed Strength and Endurance but had a baseline Charisma. It hadn’t killed him, just made his mug look a bit uglier and people around him found it harder to get along with him. If he’d had the same disparity between his Strength and Dexterity he would have been suffering a loss of motor control, unable to make finer movements and transforming into a bull in a china shop.

> You have been stripped of 1 Charisma.
>  ...
>  You have been stripped of 1 Charisma.
>  You have been stripped of 1 Charisma.
>  ...
>  He seemed to understand my question, and gestured to the small mirror in the cabin. I looked, and froze.

> Whereas I’d been proud of my appearance before, now I looked ghastly. My skin looked gray and stretched over my face like it was pulled tight around a skeleton. My beard that I’d been so proud of growing now looked like it clung to my face as though I’d been entombed with it in a watery grave for centuries.
>  ...stripped me of charisma until I was imbalanced to prove me wrong. It was worse than if I’d just had a low charisma with low total attributes. I was magically affected.